# Booking resources in SharePoint

Tags: 2007

We need to automate booking of technicians through SharePoint. We have different number of technicians available each day. The users can look at the calendar to see availability, after they select a time when a technician is available they are presented with form asking for some details. Submit a form books a technician and sends an email to IT department.

Does any one know of available products to solve this task?

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented something like this by customising the [Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 Application Template: Absence Request and Vacation Schedule Management (http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=56406562-01F9-4A18-9924-2DC0684232C8&displaylang=en)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=56406562-01F9-4A18-9924-2DC0684232C8&displaylang=en).

It is not perfect but it is a nice starting point.

Answer (score 0):

I like the Event Planning template better for my purposes but can't figure out how to limit number of people able to attend an event. Limit corresponding to how many technicians are available.